# Mysql query return multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select and return one value from 5 different columns. I want to

```
SELECT "BestLoc" from Nutrients WHERE FoodId = '$FoodId' AND CompId = '0000'.
And again where FoodId = '$FoodId' AND CompId = '0001',
And again where FoodId = '$FoodId' AND CompId = '0003',
And again where FoodId = '$FoodId' AND CompId = '0008',
And again where FoodId = '$FoodId' AND CompId = '0130'.
```

BestLoc is returned 5 times, where FoodId matches the input $FoodId, and the 5 times where CompId matches.

How is that possible to do simple? The best is if the result is returned in

```
array(
  [0] => (BestLoc value 1),
  [1] => (BestLoc value 2) and so on..
```

## Solved like this:

```
$stack = array();
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT BestLoc from Nutrients WHERE FoodId = '$FoodId' AND CompId IN ('0000', '0001', '0003', '0008', '0130')");
while($return = $stmt->fetch_assoc()){
    array_push($stack, $return['BestLoc']);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this?

```
SELECT BestLoc
 FROM Nutrients
 WHERE FoodId = "$FoodId"
 AND CompId IN ('0000','0001','0003','0008','0130')
```

Comment: I only get one result with this query.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't read this earlier. Although you have already solved your problem I just wanted to give you some extra tips. First of all, be careful with that PHP variable injecting itself into your sql query. Use a placeholder `?` and then `bindParam` and then `execute` your **prepared query**. The next thing I wanted to add is something of my own coding practices regarding those PHP vars. Unless the value is a **previously sanitized** `INTEGER`, I never inject, always concatenate. `"... WHERE someNum = $num" ...` **vs** `'... WHERE someInternal = "'.$other.'" ...`

Answer (score 2):

If I'm getting your question correctly you just seem to be looking for an `IN` clause:

```
SELECT BestLoc from Nutrients
WHERE FoodId = '$FoodId' AND CompId IN ('0000', '0001', '0003', '0008', '0130')
```

Comment: Sounds very simple, but when i use this
$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT BestLoc from Nutrients WHERE FoodId = '$FoodId' AND CompId IN ('0000', '0001', '0003', '0008', '0130')");
    $return = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
I only get one result.

Comment: You are not either iterating over the results or you only have one matching value in the table. Check the [php documentation](http://ar2.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) on how to iterate over the results

Comment: I don't think I understand. I know there's matching values in every CompId.

Comment: @Sims Certainly you get all results with this query. The problem is that you call `fetch_assoc` only once. You have to call it for every row in the resultset.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer So you would suggest some sort of while loop, or is it possible to fix in the query maybe?

Comment: @Sims If you insist on doing it in SQL, there was a third answer, that is now deleted, it suggested doing four joins on the table itself. I don't find it elegant.